# pass a ID over two modal dialogs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a list with links likte this:

```
<a data-target="changemodal" data-ds="'.$e['DS1'].'" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a data-target="changemodal" data-ds="'.$e['DS2'].'" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a data-target="changemodal" data-ds="'.$e['DS3'].'" href="#">Link 3</a>
...
```

If you click at the link a bootstrap modal open and show a confirmation text.
At the end is a "accept" or "close" button.

The modals:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-content" role="basic" id="modal_changelayout" >
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title font-purple-soft"><i class="icon-layers"></i> <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> '.APP4::SETTINGS_109.'</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            '.APP4::SETTINGS_110.'
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable hide" id="msg_box_modal_newsite">
              <div id="msg_box_text_modal_newsite"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
             <input type="hidden" name="job" value="newsite">
             <button class="btn default submitForm" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> CLOSE </button>
             <button class="btn green-meadow submitForm"  type="button" ><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> ACCEPT </button>
         </div>
          </form>
       </div>
```

If you close, nothing is to do.

If you accept i have to send the id from "data-ds" of the clicked link to a php file.

How can i do that?

Comment: are you using AJAX and JSON? this is much easier using these technologies

Comment: yes its possible to use it, but i have no idear how i can do it...

Comment: How u r showing/hiding this modal? using javascript?

Comment: via the bootstrap framework - over the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, add a html hidden text in your modal then get the value of data-ds and pass it to the container.

In this case I will add

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="data-value"/>
```

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
   var val = $(this).data("ds");
  $("#data-value").val(val);
});
```

2. Next use that value when user accept in ajax

```
$(".green-meadow").on('click',function(){
    
    var values = $('form').serialize();
    
     $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url:  'URL OF YOUR PHP FILE',
         data: values,
         dataType: 'json',
         success:function(getdata)
         { 
           if (getdata) {
              // success code here
           }else{
              // error code here
           }
         } 
     });
});
```